# Minimal spanning set $=$ basis

Tags: linear-algebra, modules

For finite dimensional vector spaces over a field it is true that if I have a spanning set whose cardinality equals the dimension of the vector space then that spanning set is a basis. Is this theorem also true for finitely generated, torsion-free module $M$ over a PID $R$. That is if I have a spanning set of cardinality $n=rank_R(M)$, then is that spanning set a basis of $M$ over $R$. Thank you for your answer in advance.